# Can I download electron built by vscode team. I mean the one whose repo is `Microsoft/vscode-electron-prebuilt` written in product.json

Tags: electron

If I built a vscode by my own and it seems some features are lost. Like search in webview because findInFrame function is not a original electron method. It seems this is an issue.
I found that when Microsoft builds vscode, they use a special electron tag and download url should be
https://api.github.com/repos/Microsoft/vscode-electron-prebuilt/releases/tags/v22.3.18-22689846
but when I open this url, it shows `Not Found`
I take a look at the @vscode/gulp-electron which helps downloading electron and there's a test suite showing we need to use a token to download
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-gulp-electron/commit/a39ee5bfd99ba44549f892ce5284d4ff2da8a8c4
Can we download that build version?

Be able to download Microsoft built electron
https://api.github.com/repos/Microsoft/vscode-electron-prebuilt/releases/tags/v22.3.18-22689846